# Android studio 1.0.2 - gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I have started using Android Studio 1.0.2 and I am trying to add Library dependency. For example I am adding loopj library in my project.

Steps which I follow:

File > Project Structure > Module(app) > Dependencies tab > Click on + icon > select loopj library > Apply > OK

Now I am getting issue of Gradle project sync failed. 
Message  : Failed to find: com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6

Somebody else facing the same problem? Please provide me suggestion if any.

Other information

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
}
```

//

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

//

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Comment: first check gradle version, android plugin version, dependencies repository sources ... in other words provide all gradle files and `gradle-wrapper.properties` file here ... without this question is off-topic *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it*

Comment: I already checked gradle version, that is 2.2.1 and dependencies :      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

Comment: now question contains all information :) ... i bet that problem is `mavenCenter` ... i think it should be `mavenCentral()`

Comment: Updated but issue is same

Comment: hmmm interesting ... ok try 2 more things: 1st get rid of `mavenCentral()` at all (is not needed there as you do not apply other plugins then  'com.android.application')  ... 2nd restart Android studio [as it always can help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)... and i'm out of solutions

Comment: you dont need to add module dependencies the way you did, you just over complicate things and end up with these issues. Just use the gradle script. remove the dependency you added via the project structure and see what the result is

Comment: also, did you add the library to your project as a jar?

Comment: No, I wrote a step above in question. File > Project Structure > Module >select app > Dependencies tab > Click on (+) icon > select any library > Apply > OK

Comment: ok, but how are you including the library, not the steps you used to add it. Example, do you add it as a jar, do you include the project as a module or do you pull it from a repository etc? So in other words, where is loopj situated in your project? hope it makes sense

Comment: @Chris with `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'` gradle should download the dependecy from jcenter repository ... So, in other words loopj is situated on [jcenter servers](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.loopj.android%3Aandroid-async-http/1.4.6/view#files)

Comment: ok cool, so leave your gradle script as it is, and simply undo the part you did in File > Project Structure > Module(app) > Dependencies tab > Click on + icon > select loopj library > Apply > OK and then sync.

Comment: just make sure that after undoing that part that your gradle script still has this line: compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'. This is all you need!

Comment: @Chris, the Project Structure dialog just modifies the build.gradle files -- your instructions about undoing changes there but then making sure the statements are in the build files doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Scott, you are right. I just figured that omitting unnecessary steps eliminates any potential problems that might creep in

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. The solution was simple, all you need is upgrade your gradle version. To do this, open your build.gradle (root project) and edit the next line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
```

So if you are using Android Studio you will notice that you are using offline mode that's not available in the new gradle version. Confirm the change and now you can download the dependencies you want.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP. Changing to 1.1 did nothing for me